# iOS app load url in webview from browser

Tags: ios, swift, webview

Iam working with webViews apps, and i have this implemented in Android and it is working, i added filter, etc.
I have the schema for http with my domain, example:

```
http://my.domain.com
```

-> And when someone click there my app open it, or:

```
http://my.domain.com/page/2
```

-> My app open the entire url in the webview using this:

```
String baseUrl = "http://my.domain.com";
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
Uri data = intent.getData();
// so if i have openened from a url its load, or just load the base
if (data!=null) {
   myWebView.loadUrl(data.toString());
} else {
   myWebView.loadUrl(baseUrl);
}
```

Basically, this is what im doind on Android right now, and im trying to translate to swift/iOS.

[image]

So now im trying to implemente this on iOS, but honestly i dont know how to do it, im using SWIFT, I hope someone can help me a bit, thanks.
I have to take the info.plist too??? thanks
And what code will be the equivalent of this from android to ios.

**UPDATE CODE IOS **

I have this in my iOS, and it works loading my base url, but i need to intercept the shared url too, already added in schema. urlschems: http

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    var URI_API_C29 : String = "http://my.domain.com"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //  INTERCEPT URL SHARED FROM OUTSIDE APP - EXAMPLE http://my.domain.com/videos
        //  HOW TO GET IT FOR REPLACE BY URI_API_C29 in case it exist

        let url = URL(string: self.URI_API_C29)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        self.webView.load(request)
    }


}
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: Use correct outlet name. Here you have `webView` instead of  `webviewInstance`. so use `webView`.

Comment: Don’t put screenshots of code in a question. Copy and paste the actual code.

Comment: sorry @Fogmeister , updated¡

Answer (score 3):

To load url in webView in Swift

Try This.
As per your code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var webV: UIWebView!
    var URI_API_C29 : String = "http://my.domain.com"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url =  NSURL(string: URI_API_C29)

        UIWebView.loadRequest(webV)(NSURLRequest(URL: url))

}
```

Comment: but how do u get the 'url' from browser?

Comment: I updated my question, showing my actual code in swift.

Comment: I updated again, but gettting errors, when you talk about a previus screen, ar u talking about the AppDelegating file? thank u

Comment: im getting an error in the last line, updated my post, sorry for the inconvenience :S im bad i know :(

Comment: and another question, in what part do u intercept the url from scheme? thanks

Comment: Try to use `UIWebView ` in place of `WKWebView`

Comment: i tried, but keep doing errors, so i just go back to how already it is loading my base url, but i need add the shared url if u read my full post, thanks for try help!! <3